# How to make UITableView refresh in tabbed interface

Tags: iphone, uitableview, nsmutablearray, refresh

I am developing a medical application with a three-tab interface. The first two tabs bring up two UITableViews, one with calculations in alphabetical order, and one with calculations in categories. Both of these tabs allow the user to enter numerical data. The third tab displays all entered and calculated data so far. The table views for the first two tabs derive from two plists. The data for the third tab derives from a NSmutablearray generated from entered and calculated data.

My issue is that the third tab for data display shows data results properly only the first time the tab is used. If the user goes back to the first two tabs and makes additional data entries and calculations, then the table view in the third tab does not refresh. Is there a spot in the view controller code for this third tab where I can force a refresh?

I have tried:
[self.tableView reloadData];
but placing this code in the view controller after
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
does not work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is the third tab's NSMutableArray updated when changes are made on the first two tabs?

Comment: All of the entered numeric data entered using the first two tabs are stored as singleton variables. The NSMutableArray is generated from these singleton variables by the third-tab view controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as `self.tableView` is not nil `reloadData` will work. It sounds like your `NSMutableArray` on the third tab is not getting updated once it is loaded. However you updated it the first time is what needs to happen. If you were updating it in `-(void)viewDidLoad` try moving it to `-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated`

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. As you suggested, I moved the code in the third-tab view controller from viewDidLoad to viewDidAppear, and now the NSMutableArray updates properly from data entered in the first two tabs.

Comment: The reason viewDidAppear did not work for me initially was that I had the code for generating the NSMutableArray in viewDidLoad, separated from reloadData under viewDidAppear. Thanks again.